# Scopus DOIs not working in article retrieval APIs

Tags: doi, scopus

I’m trying to use the Elsapy module to extract the abstracts of documents on certain topics. 
I am able to do this but, unfortunately, only for a fraction of the documents found.

For example, a particular search returns 16 documents but I am only able to extract the information (e.g. abstracts) from 4 of them.

Upon further inspection, it seems that for the documents I can’t get the abstracts of:
-Don’t have a PII
-And have DOIs that don’t work.

I have tested the DOIs in the article retrieval interactive API guide 
-The ones that returned abstracts worked fine
-The other ones return the error:
RESOURCE_NOT_FOUNDThe resource specified cannot be found.
Even though I have found the original articles and checked their DOI is correct.

An example of one that didn’t work is:
Sengupta, N. K., & Sibley, C. G. (2019). The political attitudes and subjective wellbeing of the one percent. Journal of Happiness Studies, 20(7), 2125-2140. doi:10.1007/s10902-018-0038-4

I have found that the ones that do ‘work’ all have the general form:
10.1016/j.ssmph.2019.100471
10.1016/j.apacoust.2015.03.004

Please let me know if you know why this is and how I can fix it.

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

The Article Retrieval API works for Elsevier content hosted on sciencedirect.com; all Elsevier articles have PII identifiers. The example DOI 10.1007/s10902-018-0038-4 does not work because it is published by Springer and, consequently, not available on ScienceDirect.

Kindly note that this is not a bug and everything is working as expected.